# How to use the XCode documentation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, swift

I'd like to listen in to the text change event for an NSTextField, so I looked at the docs and saw a textDidChange event. So, I connect my text field to a delegate and implement the method, run the app, and nothing happens. I also tried textDidEndEditing, but to no avail.

What are these methods for, exactly? How can one trigger them? Changing the text and tabbing out of the field or pressing enter doesn't do anything. After a bit of googling I found a controlTextDidChange method (in the NSControl parent class of NSTextField) so I implemented it, and it worked (though it had to be an override func, not just a plain func).

Handling the text change event in .NET would be a cinch, just switch to the events panel and double click on "changed" and lo and behold, it creates a method stub into which I can handle the event.

Obviously, I'm an XCode newb comparatively. What's the typical way to go about handling events in XCode/Swift? Did I go about it the wrong way, and is there a better/easier way?

Thanks.

Comment: it sounds like you have done everything right, how did you go about assigning the delegate of the textfield? through the storyboard? it could just be a case you accidentally assigned it a delegate that you arent expecting, so the callbacks are going to the wrong object

Comment: The delegate is a class added to the Objects list (it's a blue cube), and I right-clicked on the text field then dragged the Delegate item to that blue cube. I have no idea why it doesn't work, but controlTextDidChange certainly behaves as I'd expect (it's in the same delegate, in fact). Are you sure textDidChange and textDidEndEditing are actually supposed to behave like controlTextDidChange?

Comment: hmm have you tried just setting the delegate manually in code? also maybe try the `textDidBeginEditing` and see if it ever hits that. otherwise i cant really tell why it wouldnt be working, sorry

Comment: I have enough nightmares about auto layout giving me trouble. I have something that works now, so I dare not waste any more of my precious time. But thank you for responding.

Comment: @MarcFearby I have the same issue. Could you please share how you managed to solve this problem?

Comment: I kept using controlTextDidChange because it "just worked" (and continues to work). Apple's documentation leaves MUCH to be desired.